# Creating Application URL for iPhone

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am preparing to submit my iPhone app for approval. This is my first time.  One of the requirements is "Application URL".

I have done the following to create Application URL:

1. Click Foo-Info.plist
2. Right Click Information Property List"
3. Click "Add Row"
4. Select URL types
5. Expand "URL Types"
6. Expand Item 0
7. Type in "com.mycompany.Foo" in the Value field with "URL Identifier" key

I am wondering if I do this correctly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct, except you put in too much work!  When uploading an app, the application URL is a URL with **information** on the app - as in an actual website!  The only reason why apple asks you for this is because some buyers want to know exactly what they are paying for.  If you don't have one, don't worry.  This is optional.

Comment: Flafla2 is correct - this URL is simply a website that the user can visit in order to get extra information about the app if available. Most people point it at their company websites.